# Breadth-first search to solve puzzle

Tags: c#, xna, breadth-first-search

I made a [flip-game](https://icpcarchive.ecs.baylor.edu/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=217) and I'm trying to make a method to give the player a hint about their next move. Basically, I'm trying to use a breadth-first search to solve the game and then show the player the next move. I'm having some problems with my algorithm, however. The `Exit()`s are just to help me debug. Anyway, the algorithm successfully adds the current game state, `isWhite`, to `gameStates` and checks if it is a solution. The problem comes when I try to add to the queue. My code never gets to the second `Exit()` and I can't figure out why. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: Problem fixed. Now I just need to figure out what to do with the solution once I find it...

```cs
 private void hint()
    {
        Queue<bool[,]> statesToCheck = new Queue<bool[,]>();
        List<bool[,]> closedStates = new List<bool[,]>();
        bool[,] rootState = new bool[4, 4];
        rootState = (bool[,])isWhite.Clone();

        statesToCheck.Enqueue((bool[,])rootState.Clone());
        //closedStates.Add((bool[,])rootState.Clone());

        while (statesToCheck.Count() > 0)
        {
            bool solved = true;
            //checks for solution state
            rootState = statesToCheck.Dequeue();
            for (int row = 0; row < GAME_SIZE; row++)
                for (int col = 0; col < GAME_SIZE; col++)
                {
                    if (!rootState[row, col])
                        solved = false;
                }
            if (solved)
            {
                //add something to do
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("It worked");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                closedStates.Add((bool[,])rootState.Clone());
            }
            //simulates clicking each space and adds each one to statesToCheck
            for (int row = 0; row < GAME_SIZE; row++)
                for (int col = 0; col < GAME_SIZE; col++)
                {
                    bool[,] stateToChange = new bool[4, 4];
                    stateToChange = (bool[,])rootState.Clone();

                    flip(stateToChange, row, col);//gets next gameState (next node in a typical breadth-first search)

                    if (!closedStates.Contains(stateToChange))
                    {
                        //closedStates.Add((bool[,])rootState.Clone());
                        statesToCheck.Enqueue((bool[,])stateToChange.Clone());
                    }
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to debug your code why don't you use **breakpoints**, instead of calling `Exit` and close the program?
In that way you can analyze instruction by instruction and understand what's happening in your code.

**EDIT:**

The `stateToCheck` you declared is the same you've added in your `checkedStates` and the same you edit in your "simulates clicking each space and adds each one to gameStates", so I think that when you change that bidimensional array you change the one in your `List` too, because they have the same reference.

That's why `checkedStates.Contains(stateToCheck)` is always true.